# Determine current process template via TypeScript code

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on VSTS/TFS extension development work.I am trying to determine the name of current process template (whether Agile, CMMI, Scrum) via TypeScript code.

My requirement is updating workitem (bug, issue .etc.) status according to certain conditions. For same I need to identify prevalent process template name of the project. Reason is same workitem type in different templates have different status.

I am referring vsts-node-API to achieve this task. But I still couldn't figure out the way to fulfill this.
references:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/templates

Comment: The second link you provided is for work item templates. That has nothing to do with process templates.

Answer (score 1):

The response of rest api [Get a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-team-project) can return "processTemplate" parameter:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{project}?api-version={version}[&includeCapabilities={boolean}&includeHistory={boolean}]
```

Comment: It seems we do have API to get template name via "Get a team project" call, but I want do this via vss node api , and I couldn't find way to do this.
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{project}?api-version={version}[&includeCapabilities={boolean}&includeHistory={boolean}]

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: Sorry for that I've missed this feature. You could send http request directly in your project instead of doing this via vss node api.

Comment: Ill post complete answer Once I implement this. Thanks

Comment: Check this blog to see whether it is helpful: http://g-liu.com/blog/2016/07/a-strategy-for-consuming-rest-apis-in-javascript/